# Silverlight SelectedItem ComboBox filled with WCF Service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, combobox, service, selecteditem

First of all, sorry for my English...
I have something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   private MyOtherClass _other;
```

public MyOtherClass Other
   {
      get { return _other; }
      set { _other = value; }
   }
}

Now... here is the thing:

I have two WCF services... one for everything related with MyClass, and the second one for everything related with MyOtherClass, so... I fill the combo with a List of MyOtherClass, but I have to set the SelectedItem from the property on MyClass, and the references of those classes are not the same.

Please, I need help!
thanks!

Comment: didn't get your problem. if you are setting itemsSource to list of MyOtherClass then you will have to have a helper class that will fetch the MyClass List from other service and then search for the item in the list and use it instead of MyOtherClass Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to create a new Silverlight Class Library with the same structure of the Entities Class Library Project (DataModel classes mapped with NHibernate) so that when I add a Service Reference in my Silverlight Application I can reuse those classes and then the WCF Service don't create a reference for the classes I use on it.

Better explained here:

http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/11/Understanding-WCF-Services-in-Silverlight-2#WCFSilverlightConnectivityAsync